# Function Of A Data Mapper?

Tags: php, datamapper

I'm working on creating some data mappers and wanted to know if it was good practice to write a function to map post input to an object?  Would that be a function of a data mapper or should I create another class to handle input/post mapping?

Example:

```
$postdata = $_POST;
$user = $datamapper->mapInput($postdata);
$datamapper->save($user);
```

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input.  I will check out other resources in regards to this question.